# Rails pattern for destroying relationship between two ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, activerecord, model-view-controller

Say I have two models, A and B, where each has a `has_and_belongs_to_many relationship` with the other. That is, some A objects and B objects are "connected".

What would be the proper way to offer a route to destroy this relationship? It doesn't really make sense to be a destroy action on A or B's controller since we aren't destroying A or B. Is there some sort of standard way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :a do
  # use member or collection based on your needs
  member do
    # member creates a path like:
    # /a/[:id]/destroy_a_b
    delete :destroy_a_b
  end
# OR
  collection do
    # collection creates a path like:
    # /a/destroy_a_b
    delete :destroy_a_b
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
def destroy_a_b
   # with member you can do:
   @a =  A.find(params[:id])
   # but caution: you may not want to expose A outside of white-listed params

   # do your destruction
end
```

You can read more in the docs:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Thanks! This looks good, just wondering though if @a can have many b's, how could I make the route include the id of the b that is being removed ?(probably using the 'member do' syntax).